# Applying LOTUS on the unconditional expectation of a conditional random variable

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

We have that
$$X \sim\mathcal U(0,1)$$ and given X = x then $$Y\mid X=x \sim \mathcal{Binomial}(n=5,p=x)$$.

Given that $E[Y] = 5/2$, I am asked to calculate
$E[Y^2]$.

I have decided to use the computational formula for variance, to get the expression:
$$E[Y^2] = E[Y]^2 + V[Y]$$.

Where
$$V[Y] = E[(Y-E[Y])^2]$$.

I have decided to use LOUTS together with the unconditional expectation
$$E[Y] = \int_{0}^{1} E[g(y)|X=x] *f_X(x) dx$$
Such that
$$E[Y] = \int_{0}^{1} E[(Y-E[Y])^2|X=x] *f_X(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} E[(Y-E[Y])|X=x] dx$$

Now, the term $E[(Y-E[Y])^2|X=x]$ is simply the variance of a binomial distribution with parameters n = 5 and p = x.

So the full expression is:

$$V[Y] = \int_{0}^{1} 5*x(1-x) dx = 5/6$$.

Combining this, I get:

$$E[Y^2] = 75/12 + 10/12 = 85/12$$, which is wrong.

Another method would be to use, the fact that:

$$E[E[Y^2|X]] = E[Y^2]$$, which gives me the correct answer. However, I would like to know, why my original method didn't work? Am I not using LOTUS correctly or have I misunderstood something and started calculating a different statistic than $E[Y^2]$?

Comment: You should go through the computation of $E[Y^2]$ as you suggest at the end. Variance cannot be calculated as you tried. It is true that $Var(Y|X=x)=E[(Y-E[Y|X=x])^2|X=x]=nx(1-x)$ but you incorrectly replaced $E[Y|X=x]$ with $E[Y]$. In general it is easier to work with expectations than with variances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental reason why you cannot say $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \int_{x=0}^1 \operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X = x]f_X(x) \, dx,$$ is because this doesn't take into account an additional source of variation in $Y$ as a result of the variability in $X$.  All that the integral on the RHS is doing is calculating a weighted average of the conditional variance of $Y$ given $X$, weighted by the density of $X$.  As such, what it is really calculating is
$$\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X]] = \int_{x=0}^1 \operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X = x]f_X(x) \, dx.  \tag{1}$$

However, the law of total variance states that
$$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]]. \tag{2}$$
The missing second term is the variance of the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X$.  A proof of this law follows:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[Y]
&= \operatorname{E}\left[(Y - \operatorname{E}[Y])^2\right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[Y^2\right] - \operatorname{E}[Y]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{E}[Y^2 \mid X]\right] - \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{E}[Y^2 \mid X] - \operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]^2 + \operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]^2\right] - \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X]] + \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]^2\right] - \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]]. \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

What is this second term in your case?  It is
$$\operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]] = \int_{x=0}^1 \left(\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X = x] - \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]]\right)^2 f_X(x) \, dx. \tag{4}$$
Notice that the double expectation $\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]]$ in the integrand is **not** a function of $x$.  It is a constant, and in fact, is simply $\operatorname{E}[Y]$.

So after having computed $\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X]] = \frac{5}{6}$, from $(1)$, we can compute from $(4)$ that
$$\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X] = 5X, \quad \operatorname{E}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]] = \operatorname{E}[5X] = \frac{5}{2},$$
hence
$$\operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]] = \int_{x=0}^1 \left(5x - \tfrac{5}{2}\right)^2 \, dx = \frac{25}{12}. \tag{5}$$
Therefore
$$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \frac{5}{6} + \frac{25}{12} = \frac{35}{12}, \tag{6}$$
hence
$$\operatorname{E}[Y^2] = \operatorname{Var}[Y] + \operatorname{E}[Y]^2 = \frac{35}{12} + \frac{25}{4} = \frac{55}{6}. \tag{7}$$

The same answer could also have been obtained without the law of total variance by writing
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y^2] &= \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{E}[Y^2 \mid X]\right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid X] + \operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]^2\right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[5X(1-X) + (5X)^2\right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[20X^2 + 5X] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[20(X - 1/2)^2 + (20X - 5) + 5X] \\
&= 20 \operatorname{E}[(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2] + 25 \operatorname{E}[X] - 5 \\
&= 20 \operatorname{Var}[X] + \frac{25}{2} - 5 \\
&= \frac{20}{12} + \frac{25}{2} - 5 \\
&= \frac{55}{6}. \tag{8}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{gather*}
E[Y^2\mid X]=Var[Y\mid X]+E[Y\mid X]^2=nX(1-X)+n^2X^2=(n^2-n)X^2+nX\\
E[Y^2]=\int_0^1E[Y^2\mid X=x]dx=\int_0^1((n^2-n)x^2+nx)dx=\frac{2n^2+n}{6}=\frac{55}{6}
\end{gather*}